# Dimension Lookup/Update Variable for Target Table

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am passing information from a select in a previous step to the Dimension lookup/update step. The problem I have is the following: I am passing the table name and fields dynamically as a loop. So each iteration is going to have a different table name and different fields. In the Dimension lookup/update step the Dimension Fields are shown by being pulled from the table name written in the Target table field. Since I put a variable there no fields are shown. How would those fields show when I use a variable in the Target Table field.

Also, in the Stream fields to compare with, I am passing the fields there dynamically again. So from the previous step which is table input and I select * and the table name is the variable. So no constant fields would show.

How would I map the fields? Note that all the field names are identical.

I want to be able to map the fields somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to loop is correct, but instead of looping a normal transformation where you set a table by variable, you should set the metadata (table + columns) directly via metadata injection.

This requires you to fetch list of tables and columns beforehand, and feed them in the ETL metadata call, which allows you to force them in certain metadata fields of the steps in the underlying transformation.

More info [here](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/ETL_Metadata_Injection)

Comment: Yes I am using Metadata Injection step for the Type of Dimension Update to be Punch Through. I am not sure however how that would happen for the table and columns. Could you help me?

Comment: How should this happen? I'm not sure.

Comment: There is a full explanation + sample in the link I provided. You just have to replace excel by a query on db to get the database names and columns.. Best might be to run a query on a parent level to retrieve the table names, then use a transformation executor (one execution per row) to go to table level. Then query the columns for the table, so you get x rows with each the table_name and a column, and just feed that in the metadata. (you might want to add some extra info for the underlying steps. Maybe it also needs datatype per column). Thats all i can say on the info you have given.